# How to find if one value of dictionary has certain value in a list of dicts

Tags: python

This is my list:

```py
list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 4, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 5, 'custom': 'two'},
]
```

I'm going to find which `id`s have only `custom` value of `two`. If they have `one` or (`one` and `two`), that's OK. The problem should be ones which have `two`.

This is my attempt:

```py
for x in list1:
    uid = x['id']
    if uid == x['id'] and x['custom'] == 'two':
        print(x)
```

Expected output should be `id`s 5 and 2.

Current output prints 1, 2, 3 and 5.

Comment: And what's the problem with your attempt? Aside from that `uid == x['id']` is redundant given `uid = x['id']`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe current output shows 1, 2, 3 and 5 which is not correct

Comment: Why are 1 and 3 not correct?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen because they have both one and two, while 5 and 2 have only two.

Comment: It seems like your first step needs to be _grouping_ by ID; you cannot determine that during a simple loop over the list, each dictionary is considered independently in your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 4, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 5, 'custom': 'two'},
]

print({d['id'] for d in list1}
    - {d['id'] for d in list1 if d['custom'] != 'two'})
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuha3GJ1zMotLDBVsFaK5FICgWj0zRd1KwVBHQT25tLgkPxfIUc_PS1Wv1UGWN0KRLynPR5M3JqDfkCT9mPImBMw3xaY_louroCgzr0SjOiUapCxWIS2_SCFFITNPARwItWATdBVwSCtkpikAZaDGxioo2kJN1oSEJTRIYUELAA)

Comment: I really love your way:) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way could be to aggregate into a `defaultdict` and find entries which only have a `two` against them -

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for entry in list1:
    dd[entry['id']].append(entry['custom'])
print([key for key in dd if dd[key] == ['two']])
```

**Output**

```py
[2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe first we could retrieve the IDs that have `one` as their value, and then proceed to check if any of those IDs also have `two` as their value.

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 2, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 1, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 3, 'custom': 'two'},
    {'id': 4, 'custom': 'one'},
    {'id': 5, 'custom': 'two'},
]

ids_with_one = defaultdict(bool)
for item in list1:
    if item['custom'] == 'one':
        ids_with_one[item['id']] = True

for item in list1:
    if item['custom'] == 'two' and not ids_with_one[item['id']]:
        print(item['id'])
```

Fiddle: https://www.online-python.com/nSLCTrb8kj

Answer (score 2):

I would aggregate the "custom" values as [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) per "id", then filter the ids  that match `{'two'}`:

```
values = {}
for d in list1:
    values.setdefault(d['id'], set()).add(d['custom'])
# {1: {'one', 'two'}, 2: {'two'}, 3: {'one', 'two'}, 4: {'one'}, 5: {'two'}}

out = {k for k,v in values.items() if v == {'two'}}
# {2, 5}
```

Similar logic using the [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) library:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.DataFrame(list1).groupby('id')['custom'].agg(set)

out = s.index[s=={'two'}].tolist()
# [2, 5]
```

Or as a one-liner with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (this code is not necessarily more efficient than the pure python version since you first have to sort the dictionaries!):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

out = [k for k,g in groupby(sorted(list1, key=itemgetter('id')),
                            key=itemgetter('id'))
       if {d['custom'] for d in g} == {'two'}]
# [2, 5]
```